# Object.create implementation ES3

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

while reading a book (JavaScript : The definitive Guide) i have found a piece of code that implement **Object.create** in ES3:

```
// inherit() returns a newly created object that inherits properties from the
// prototype object p. It uses the ECMAScript 5 function Object.create() if
// it is defined, and otherwise falls back to an older technique.
function inherit(p) {
if (p == null) throw TypeError(); // p must be a non-null object
if (Object.create)
// If Object.create() is defined...
return Object.create(p);
//
then just use it.
var t = typeof p;
// Otherwise do some more type checking
if (t !== "object" && t !== "function") throw TypeError();
function f() {};
// Define a dummy constructor function.
f.prototype = p;
// Set its prototype property to p.
return new f();
// Use f() to create an "heir" of p.
}
```

and there is my implementation :

```
function inherit(proto) {
        var o = {};

        if(typeof proto != "function" && typeof proto != "object")
                throw TypeError();

        o.prototype = proto;
        return o;
}
```

- i Don't understand why the book author have created a function and use it as constructor to return the new object that have a prototype **p**, while its possible to simply **o.prototype = proto**

Comment: Try use `Object.keys` on your output from `inherit` :-). This will tell you what's up

Comment: And btw, you want to keep `o` in the proper scope: `var o = {};`...

Comment: i have tried to loop over Object.keys(o) using (for .. in) but i get only 'undefined' why??

Comment: "a prototype" (from which an object inherits) and a `.prototype` property are completely different things.